# Is PHP Division Broken Or Is It My Code?

Tags: php

**My PHP code:**

```
<?php
      $fnd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Selles WHERE ItemID='$gI->ID'");
      $numba = mysql_num_rows($getItem);
      $ciunt = 0;
      $prc = 0;
      while($eye = mysql_fetch_object($fnd)){
          $price2 = $eye->Price;
          $prc = $prc + $price2;
      }

     if ($numba != 0){
            $SalePrices = $prc/$numba;
            $SalePrices = "<font color='green'><b>B$".number_format($SalePrices)."</b></green>";
     } else {
             $SalePrices = "<b>N/A</b>";
     }
?>
```

Sorry for random variable names, they make sense to me and the rest of my code. But what I need is for all the things in Selles to be added together, which works fine. Then it tries to divide $prc (price, all of the Selles added together) by $numba (the number of times it has been purchased) to work out the average.

I don't understand; is it my code or has PHP gone wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some output of your current script and a more detailed description fo what you want to achieve/what is wrong with the output

Comment: Do a var_dump on `$prc` and `$numba`. What does it output?

Comment: 1. don.t use ancien markup; 2. `SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Selles WHERE...` is your friend; 3. code should make sense to everybody who may read it, incidentally people on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the $numba will always be integers? Can it have null values or empty string or non integers? I would suggest modifying your code as follows.

```
if (is_int($numba) && ! empty($numba)) {
   $SalePrices = $prc/$numba;
} else {
   // Else block
}
```